# How can I change the bg-color with knockout.js css-binding when the element is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FG1ZE0NJ4ZX7

So, I made a progress breadcrumb, but I want to make the background color of each progress change when it's clicked by using knockout.js css-binding.

How can I apply the

```
.selected {
    color: white;
    background: #369F00;
}
```

style when the button is clicked and change it back to its original color when a different button is clicked by using knockout.js css-binding?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code example is incomplete, it doesn't show any of the knockout/javascript side of things.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. It works well if you need complete control over the style from Javascript, Otherwise I'd suggest placing those styles into a class, and using the css binding instead, to apply a class when an observable boolean is true.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.styling = ko.observable({
     'color': 'black',
     'background': 'white'
    });
    
    this.changeStyles = function(){
        this.styling({
         'color': 'white',
         'background': '#369F00'
        });
    };
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
body { font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; }
.liveExample { padding: 1em; border: 1px solid #CCC; max-width: 655px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample' data-bind='click: changeStyles, style:styling'>
  Some Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to solve the problem using the css data-binding, keeping things nice and classful.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.isSelected = ko.observable(false);

    this.changeStyles = function(){
        this.isSelected(true);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
body { font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; }
.liveExample { padding: 1em; border: 1px solid #CCC; max-width: 655px; }
.selected {color: white; background: #369F00}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample' data-bind='click: changeStyles, css:{selected:isSelected}'>
  Some Content
</div>
```